# CSS height property set incorrectly, dont know how to fix

Tags: html, css

I have this problem where my height property of a certain div doesnt work as i would like to, and i have no idea how to fix it.
**SCSS:**

```
            .security{
                border: 3px #1D3176 solid;
                display: flex;
                h2{
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 25%;
                    left: 70%;
                }
                img{
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 25%;
                    left: 5%;
                }
                .intro{
                    position: relative;
                    width: 25%;
                    left: 70%;
                    top: 40px;
                }
                h4{
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 30%;
                    left: 35%;
                }
                .text{
                    position: relative;
                    width: 30%;
                    left: 10%;
                    top: 50px;
                }
            }
            .human-rights{
                border: 3px #1D3176 solid;
                display: flex;
                h2{
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 25%;
                    left: 5%;
                }
                img{
                    position: absolute;
                    left: 35%;
                    width: 30%;
                }
                .intro{
                    position: relative;
                    width: 25%;
                    left: 5%;
                    top: 40px;
                }
                .a{
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 25%;
                    left: 70%;
                }
                .text1{
                    text-align: center;
                    position: relative;
                    width: 25%;
                    left: 46%;
                    top: 50px;
                }
                .b{
                    position: absolute;
                    width: 25%;
                    left: 70%;
                    top: 100px;
                }
                .text2{
                    text-align: center;
                    position: relative;
                    width: 25%;
                    left: 20%;
                    top: 150px;
                }
            }
```

**HTML:**

```
        <div id="sec-counc" class="security">
                <h2>Security Council</h2>
                <img id="sec-counc-img" src="imgs/SecCounc.png" alt="Security council committee">
                <div class="intro">The SC is the only committee, which can pass legally binding 
                    resolutions and deploy humanitarian and military missions, but it is also the 
                    only one where some countries posses veto powers. The challenge is making the best 
                    of the former, while working around the latter.</div>
                <h4>Topic 1:</h4>
                <div class="text">Resolving the political crisis in the Federal Democratic 
                    Republic of Ethiopia relating to the uprisings in the Tigray, Oromia, 
                    and Benishangul-Gumuz regions.</div>
            </div>
            <div class="human-rights">
                <h2>Human Rights Council</h2>
                <img src="imgs/HumanRightsCounc.png" alt="Human right council committee">
                <div class="intro">The United Nations was founded on the prospect of the promotion of human rights. 
                    Unfortunately, most member countries did not get the memo, and continue to violate the human rights. 
                    The HCR has special authorization to launch public awareness campaigns, and send communications 
                    (official letters, which inform of human rights violations, and encourage their stoppage, being 
                    sent to governments, IGOs, NGOs, and companies). It is up to the delegates to make the most of
                    these limited tools.</div>
                <h4 class="a">Topic 1:</h4>
                <div class="text1">Addressing the violations of human rights caused by 
                    inter-racial hatred especially in multi-ethnic states.</div>
                <h4 class="b">Topic 2:</h4>
                <div class="text2">Addressing the status of human rights of drug dealers and drug users.</div>
            </div>
```

but it does this (the borders should show the height of it, as you can see they dont really fit.):
[image]
What Im trying to achieve here is the yellow pic being one property and then the blue picture being under it no matter what. I tried doing it with hard coding height: npx; but it doesnt work because when i scale the width up it messes it up again. Please help me im desperate.

Comment: Your code is not in the right format, please make sure all your code is shared properly. That would help us in finding your problems

Comment: Could you specify? Im new here

Comment: Your images are not working due to local images. On top of your CSS, it has `border: 3px #1D3176 solid; display: flex;`, but no classes/ids reference

Comment: Fixed, was there the whole time i just didnt copy it lol

Comment: Is you CSS actually LESS or SCSS? Because [nesting CSS is not yet supported in any browser](https://caniuse.com/css-nesting).

Comment: Its scss my bad, completly forgot bout that lol. Updated. I have a translator from scss to css so its ok

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `position: absolute` to adjust your elements' position. That will cause a lot more problems in responsive as well as element re-positioning

Instead of that, I'd propose using `flex` for re-positioning

```css
.flexbox {
  border: 3px #1D3176 solid;
  display: flex;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.flex-item {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.topic {
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

.center-text {
  text-align: center;
}

.intro {
  text-align: justify;
}

h4 {
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="sec-counc" class="security flexbox">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img id="sec-counc-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/52/Emblem_of_the_United_Nations.svg/120px-Emblem_of_the_United_Nations.svg.png" alt="Security council committee">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <h4 class="center-text">Topic 1:</h4>
    <div class="text center-text">Resolving the political crisis in the Federal Democratic Republic of Ethiopia relating to the uprisings in the Tigray, Oromia, and Benishangul-Gumuz regions.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <h2 class="center-text">Security Council</h2>
    <div class="intro">The SC is the only committee, which can pass legally binding resolutions and deploy humanitarian and military missions, but it is also the only one where some countries posses veto powers. The challenge is making the best of the former, while working
      around the latter.</div>
  </div>

</div>
<div class="human-rights flexbox">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <h2 class="center-text">Human Rights Council</h2>
    <div class="intro">The United Nations was founded on the prospect of the promotion of human rights. Unfortunately, most member countries did not get the memo, and continue to violate the human rights. The HCR has special authorization to launch public awareness campaigns,
      and send communications (official letters, which inform of human rights violations, and encourage their stoppage, being sent to governments, IGOs, NGOs, and companies). It is up to the delegates to make the most of these limited tools.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://reliefweb.int/sites/reliefweb.int/files/resources/1024px-United_Nations_Human_Rights_Council_Logo.svg_.png" alt="Human right council committee">
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    <div class="topic">
      <h4 class="a center-text">Topic 1:</h4>
      <div class="text1 center-text">Addressing the violations of human rights caused by inter-racial hatred especially in multi-ethnic states.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="topic">
      <h4 class="b center-text">Topic 2:</h4>
      <div class="text2 center-text">Addressing the status of human rights of drug dealers and drug users.</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

SCSS version here https://jsfiddle.net/zu08hfva/

Comment: Ok, ill have a look, though i think it will work. Is it possible to set the top to something on this code? I think ill need that. Thanks!

Comment: Could you tell me the case which you need the top? @Karafakeu

Comment: Basicly the one you showed me had all the elements sorted from the top, i would a) need them vertically centered if possible, if not then at least move them around a bit with top:;

Comment: which elements should be vertically centered? @Karafakeu

Comment: I think it will actually be fine. The pic and the other elements i want to be the same hight and just kinda have them look cool when next to each other. Ill tell you if it worked

Comment: the actual image is not squared with content, but we can make images in center of its containers. How do you think about it, @Karafakeu?

Comment: Ok so, this solution worked perfect for me, the top element included. only thing is that the img is left on both cases. Would it be possible to like switch it up so its once on the left and once on the middle?

Comment: which image is on the left? and which one is on the middle? @Karafakeu

Comment: They are both on the left, tho i want the first one to be on the left and the second one on the middle

Comment: Oh that's weird, could you check this sandbox https://jsfiddle.net/zu08hfva/? I think the first image is on the left, and the second image on the middle

Comment: So um im kinda dumb. It works as intended, i just switched the parts in html so they werent rotated. Understandable? now i have another issue, i basicly would need one version of the html for one width for pc, and another version of the html code for width for mobile. Is that somehow achievable?

Comment: You can check this version https://jsfiddle.net/sf7hme4g/, @Karafakeu. I added media query to control mobile display

Comment: Yea, i have that too, but that is not what im looking for. I want it to be like the one you sent me on pc, and on mobile it would be how you did it but in this order: Name, photo, intro, topics. On all of them. Get it?

Comment: hmm but their orders are not the same on desktop, right? On UI, we basically display what we have. If you want to switch elements' positions that would involve some logic in Javascript @Karafakeu